# Possible outcomes of needing a Tree Report before Mortage? [UK]

Tags: mortgage, united-kingdom

Whilst applying for a mortgage on a house I've needed to get an arboricultural report due to the valuer requesting it due to some trees on the property.

The report came back advising that a tree be removed eventually.

I've just sent this off to the mortgage company.

**What possible outcomes could they come back with?**

- Will they still grant the mortgage?
- Could there be conditions on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, they offered the mortgage with the condition that the tree was removed.

They wouldn't offer the mortgage with the tree still present.

Comment: The owners of the house removed the tree in question and the mortgage was offered and we moved just before Christmas.